# chrome not displaying video in flash

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I don't understand. I'm trying to embed a video on my site. works perfectly on all browsers (even IE8) but not chrome... tested on several machines using windows 7

this is the embed code:

```
<object height="226" id="ce_93792260" width="400">
<param name="movie" value="http://current.com/e/93792260/en_US" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<embed allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" height="226" 
src="http://current.com/e/93792260/en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" wmode="transparent">
    </embed></object>
```

you can see the embed on the page here: http://www.radicalislam.org/videos/american-born-baptist-now-ruthless-islamic-terrorist

Comment: Please multi-line your code so it's easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution.
need to delete the file(s) gcswf32.dll
don't forget to close chrome before.

source:
http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2004